# how to pass arguments to shell script that should be executed in container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Consider i have this docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  webapp:
   image: some_image:repo
   container_name: my_container
   ports:
    - "8080:8080"
    #entrypoint : /home/my_tool/
   command: bash -c "/home/my_tool/runSomeScript.sh argument1 argument2  && /bin/bash"
  stdin_open: true
  tty: true
```

And this is my script inside the image/container that will be running.

```
  $ cat runSomeScript.sh
  #!/bin/bash
  echo "First arg: $1"
  echo "Second arg: $2"
```

So, when i execute docker-compose up command ... i can't pass the arguments to container which should execute the bash script with these values...

Need to notice that if i do this only without arguments like :

```
  command: bash -c "/home/my_tool/runSomeScript.sh && /bin/bash"
```

and also script without arguments like this :

```
   $ cat runSomeScript.sh
  #!/bin/bash
  echo "First arg: ddd"
  echo "Second arg: fff"
```

then container ups and just execute shell script.
But with passed arguments it doesn't work. What i miss here.

Answer (score 0):

Don't fixate on tricks to "keep your container running".  Have your container run its process, and when it exits, the container exits.  In Compose syntax you can simplify this to

```yaml
# Compose provides an sh -c '...' wrapper for you
# Do not try to run the main container process, then a shell
command: /home/my_tool/runSomeScript.sh argument1 argument2
```

If you want to launch this for a one-off execution you can [`docker-compose run`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/) it, providing your own command line.

```
docker-compose run webapp /home/my_tool/runSomeScript.sh baz quux
```

Comment: I tried as you say but container is stopping, And i need to continue running till the moment when i decide to stop it.
Secondly, it created new container with name like 'docker_webapp_run_35f57e56dd78' and not as i defined in docker-compose.yml. Any thoughts how to handle with this two issues?

Answer (score 0):

Passing properties in docker-compose can be done as follows

```
command: bash -c "startup.sh" param1 param2  ;
```

You can also pass variables from env by setting env variables as follows

```
environment:
     PARAM1: ${PARAM1}
     PARAM2: ${PARAM1}
  command: bash -c "startup.sh" ${PARAM1} ${PARAM12}  ;
```

in .env, set values

```
PARAM1=ddd 
PARAM2=fff
```